# Why do I get different answers when I use math.fmod and just the mod operator? (for integers)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multiplication, modulo

I write the following code to find the maximum product subarray:

```
def ans(arr, n):
    M = 1000000007
    cur_max = cur_min = ans = arr[0] % M
    for i in range(1, n):
        tmp = cur_max
        cur_max = max(arr[i], cur_min * arr[i]% M, cur_max * arr[i] % M)
        cur_min = min(arr[i], cur_min * arr[i] % M, tmp * arr[i] % M)
        ans = max(ans, cur_max)
    return ans % M
```

When I use it on
array = [6, -3, -10, 0, 2], I get an answer: 999999989 
Whereas, when I change it to

```
from math import *
def ans(arr, n):
    M = 1000000007
    cur_max = cur_min = ans = arr[0]
    for i in range(1, n):
        tmp = cur_max
        cur_max = max(arr[i], int(fmod(cur_min * arr[i], M)), int(fmod(cur_max * arr[i], M)))
        cur_min = min(arr[i], int(fmod(cur_min * arr[i], M)), int(fmod(tmp * arr[i], M)))
        ans = max(ans, cur_max)
    return ans
```

I get the answer: 180 
The only change I made was to use the fmod function and then convert it into integers rather than using the mod (%) operator. Why do I get totally different answers?

Comment: from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.fmod): Note that the Python expression x % y may not return the same result.

Comment: @deadshot the only ambiguity they mention here is for float data type but here we have all integers.

Comment: A minimal example may help. (e.g. which numbers gives a different results. IIRC there are other possible changes: different convention when we have minus signs. it is hidden somewhere in documentation, and without a clear answer

Comment: The first initialises ``cur_max = cur_min = ans = arr[0] % M``, the second just ``cur_max = cur_min = ans = arr[0]``. Is this intentional?

Comment: `-6 % M` gives different results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` operator and `math.fmod` do not perform the same modulo operation. In specific, the handling of negative numbers is different:

> #### [math.fmod(x, y)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.fmod)
>
> [..] The intent of the C standard is that `fmod(x, y)` be exactly (mathematically; to infinite precision) equal to `x - n*y` for some integer `n` such that the *result has the same sign as `x`* and magnitude less than `abs(y)`. Python’s `x % y` returns a *result with the sign of `y`* instead, and may not be exactly computable for float arguments. [..]

> #### [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)
>
> [..] The modulo operator always yields a *result with the same sign as its second operand* (or zero); [..] The function `math.fmod()` *returns a result whose sign matches the sign of the first argument* instead [..]. Which approach is more appropriate depends on the application.

```py
>>> def test_mod(a, b): print('%-op:', a % b, 'fmod:', fmod(a, b))
>>> test_mod(10, 12)
%-op: 10 fmod: 10.0
>>> test_mod(-10, 12)
%-op: 2 fmod: -10.0
>>> test_mod(10, -12)
%-op: -2 fmod: 10.0
```

---

Both `ans` variants will give the same result for *positive* inputs:

```py
>>> perc_ans([6, 3, 10, 0, 2], 5)
180
>>> math_ans([6, 3, 10, 0, 2], 5)
180
>>> perc_ans([6, -3, -10, 0, 2], 5)
999999989
>>> math_ans([6, -3, -10, 0, 2], 5)
180
```

Comment: And here the link for the documentation of % (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks a lot, I've added this to the answer now.